# Model nested list returns null in controller

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

Here is model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}        
    public List<Commodity> commodities { get; set; }
}


 public class Commodity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description{get; set;}       
}
```

when trying to get list of my commodities

```
public ActionResult Commodities(int id)
    {
        var cat = db.Categories.Find(id);            
        var comms = cat.commodities;
        if (comms != null)
        {
            return View(comms);
        }
       ....
    }
```

get null value. But there are some values in the database. Checked in debug -"Id" value is correct, all other fields in model are correct, exept for the list, which is null. Why? Thanks.

Comment: `public List<Commodity> commodities` property should be virtual to work with EntityFramework. It's in case if you are using it, as from question it's hard to understand what do you use

Comment: Please add the db initialisation code to your answer.